# How to create a db model with table rows that have relationships to ever growing attributes?

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling

For example, if I have a table that takes some type of 'item' whether it be products, animals, what have you, and I need to also store their attributes that can grow over time. What is the best way to model?

One way would be:

```
CREATE TABLE item
(
   item_id int,
   name varchar(255),
   description varchar(255),
);

CREATE TABLE item_attr
(
   item_attr_id int,
   item_id int,
   name varchar(255),
   description varchar(255),
   value varchar(255)
)
```

Now if I add an item to the items table, and this item gets 100 different attributes with name, description, any possible value (number, text, etc), then I would have 100 rows just for that one item in the item_attr table. Is that the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether the attributes are share between items. In that case you would create them in a separate table and create linktable between them

```
CREATE TABLE item
(
   item_id int,
   name varchar(255),
   description varchar(255),
);

CREATE TABLE attr
(
   attr_id int,
   name varchar(255),
   description varchar(255),
)


CREATE TABLE item_attr
(
   item_attr_id int,
   item_id int,
   attr_id int,
   value varchar(255)
)
```

Comment: Let's assume that the attributes aren't shared between items and all items are different.

Comment: In that case I would favor your solution. But in some sense you create your own relational model by abstracting your table, I mean in theory you could store anything in these tables.